# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2009, Spring boot entity manager can not make a query with XMLELEMENT, XMLFOREST, XMLAGG

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I can not execute below select I am getting error "No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2009" but dialect in my Intellij Idea is set to oracle sql

```
List<Object> results = super.entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT XMLELEMENT(PLAYERS, XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(PLAYER, XMLFOREST(ID_USER as ID_USER, NAME as NAME, LAST_NAME as LAST_NAME)))) players from AIRSOFTWEB_USER").getResultList();
```

I also execute query below in DataGrip and it works

```
SELECT
XMLELEMENT(AIRSOFTWEB_USER,
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(AIRSOFTWEB_USER,
            XMLFOREST(ID_USER as ID, NAME as NAME, LAST_NAME as LAST_NAME)))) player
from AIRSOFTWEB_USER;
```

And the result was

```
<AIRSOFTWEB_USER><AIRSOFTWEB_USER><ID>1</ID><NAME>Matej Janotka</NAME><LAST_NAME>Janotka</LAST_NAME></AIRSOFTWEB_USER></AIRSOFTWEB_USER>
```

When i try some other primitive query like: `Select * from AIRSOFTWEB_USER;` entityManager work fine and the result is return in List of objects as is should.

But weird is that in DataGrip and also in Intellij I am getting an error "Unable to resolve column" where to tag name should be (I am geting it when I hover mouse over red text can be see on pictres below) but still, in DataGrip the query is executed whit out problems

**DataGrip screen**
[image: DataGrip scrrenshot]

**Intellij screen**

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you have fixed this issue, but I faced the same problem and it was because hibernate couldn't map to Java Object.